# Scrollbar implemented into textbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a fairly simple e-reader, and I've managed to use tkinter to create something akin to one. But what I can't seem to work out is how to create a scrollbar to allow the user to scroll through the text at will. I can get it working in other pieces of coding, but I can't make it work within this program  and I can't work out what the problem is. I've put my simple e-reader, without the attempted scrollbar below.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import ScrolledText

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("File dialog")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        menubar = Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)

        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.onOpen)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)        

        self.txt = Text(self)
        self.txt.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


    def onOpen(self):

        ftypes = [('Python files', '*.py'), ('All files', '*')]
        dlg = tkFileDialog.Open(self, filetypes = ftypes)
        fl = dlg.show()

        if fl != '':
            text = self.readFile(fl)
            self.txt.insert(END, text)

    def readFile(self, filename):

        f = open(filename, "r")
        text = f.read()
        return text

self.txt = ScrolledText(self, undo=True)
self.txt['font'] = ('consolas', '12')
self.txt.pack(expand=True, fill='both')


def main():

    root = Tk()
    ex = Example(root)
    root.geometry("300x250+300+300")
    root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How are we going to know what you're doing wrong if you omit the one piece of code that isn't working? Please show us the code _with_ the scrollbar that's not working. Also, your indentation looks messed up -- look toward the end with `def main(0)` and the code that follows.

Comment: Have you tried using `ScrolledText`?

Comment: Sorry you're right Bryan, I should have included all of the coding.

And yes Tobias, scrolledtext is the one I've been using as it was recommended to me, but I can't seem to implement it. I'm sure it's something very stupid that I'm doing, but I just can't see it as a newbie.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand what you mean Tobias. Sorry, I know I'm being quite dim here

Comment: Well, that new block of code, `self.txt = ScrolledText...`, does not really sit there, outside of the class, or does it? If it does, move it to where the original `self.txt=Text...` is; otherwise please be more explicit as to what the problem is. Are you getting an error message, or does is not behave as intended?

Comment: Ahh sorry yeah I was being an idiot. Okay what happens is that when I run it, everything works, apart from the scrollbar. I can open any txt file and read it, but there's no scrollbar to the side allowing me to scroll down to read more.

Comment: Okay I edited the code in the first post, and an image is linked here:

http://tinypic.com/r/2yl4655/5

I just know I'm doing something really dumb, but despite both you and Bryan helping me, and looking at tutorials I just can't spot the problem which I know is there.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't know where it should be going @tobias_k

Comment: Okay, just to make sure, before I post a stupid answer: Those three lines starting with `self.txt = ScrolledText(...` are placed _right there_, right above the `main` function, in your actual code you are running? How could you even execute this without getting a `NameError`?

Comment: I am in fact getting a name error. Sorry. I had it running a minute ago but I don't know what I changed now. However, it's safe to say that what you think is a stupid answer is going to solve everything on my side of things.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a scrollbar to a text widget requires you to do two things in addition to creating the actual widgets:

1. you must set the `yscrollcommand` attribute of the text widget to point to the `set` method of the scrollbar
2. you must set the `command` attribute of the scrollbar to point to the `yview` method of the text widget

For example:

```
self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
self.scrollbar.configure(command=self.text.yview)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've long wondered whether this could *really* be the answer to your question, but after the discussion in the comments, it seems it is: You just put the code creating the `ScrolledText` in the wrong place!

Try moving these three lines (that are now outside of the class, causing a `NameError` for `self`)

```
self.txt = ScrolledText(self, undo=True)
self.txt['font'] = ('consolas', '12')
self.txt.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
```

to where these lines are in your `initUI` method (replace these lines)

```
self.txt = Text(self)
self.txt.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

With other words, in your `initUI` method, instead of creating a `Text` widget, create a `ScrolledText`. Also, change `import ScrolledText` to `from ScrolledText import ScrolledText` so that `ScrolledText` is the actual widget, and not the module defining the widget.

Comment: Yep, I'm an idiot. Thank you very much Tobias! That's sorted things out!

Comment: @Rusky Glad I could help. As it seems that this solved your problem, would you please 'accept' this answer? (the little checkmark symbol to the left)